# Why are there so few synonyms for *interesting*?

Tags: vocabulary

Why are there so few synonyms for the word *interesting*? Really the only entirely interchangeable synonym is *curious* but it's rarely used now in this context. And *interesting* is a word used a lot and it would seem that we would all benefit if there were atlernatives at our disposal.

Comment: alluring
amusing
attractive
beautiful
compelling
curious
delightful
engaging
exotic
fascinating
impressive
intriguing
lovely
pleasing
provocative
readable
refreshing
stimulating
striking
thought-provoking
unusual
absorbing
affecting
arresting
captivating
enchanting
engrossing
enthralling
entrancing
fine
gripping
inviting
prepossessing
riveting
stirring
winning
charismatic
elegant
exceptional
gracious
magnetic
pleasurable

Comment: When copying other peoples' work maybe you should credit them rather than passing it off as your own.

Comment: I would think that https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/interesting needs no introduction.

Comment: That's not the point. Plagiarism should be frowned upon. When you type sth in and put your name on it you claim you're the autor which in this case you aren't.

Comment: I should note that I'm recovering from kidney stone surgery and I needed to pee really bad,

Comment: @HotLicks - Hmmm. Interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, depending on the specific "shade" of interest, there is also "intriguing", if your interest is piqued, and "fascinating", if you are extremely interested.

And I actually wouldn't say that interesting is entirely interchangeable with curious, because curious indicates peculiarity, while interesting doesn't.